# Laravel recovering the id of the return of a json

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm having a problem retrieving data from a select.

When I perform the following select

```
$Projeto = $this->ModelProjeto
->select('projeto.*','tipoprojeto.descricao')
->join('tipoprojeto','tipoprojeto.id','=','projeto.tipoprojeto')->get();
```

and returns json

```
[{"id":1,"descricao":"house","tipoprojeto":1,"tipoprojetodescricao":"Engenharia Civil"}]
```

When I try to retrieve the json id with the following command: `return $Projeto->id;` error appears

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

if I used the find method, it would work normally, but it is not possible to use join, so how do I access Project-> id using the -> get () method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get()` method returns a collection, not an individual item.

```
 $Projetos = $this->ModelProjeto
    ->select('projeto.*','tipoprojeto.descricao')
    ->join('tipoprojeto','tipoprojeto.id','=','projeto.tipoprojeto')
    ->get();

// you would need to loop the $Projetos to get each id

$Projetos->each->id

// or use the first() method if you know only one item is returned

$Projeto = $this->ModelProjeto
    ->select('projeto.*','tipoprojeto.descricao')
    ->join('tipoprojeto','tipoprojeto.id','=','projeto.tipoprojeto')
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the JSON, this is an array, so instead of using `get()`, use `first()`

```
$Projeto = $this->ModelProjeto
->select('projeto.*','tipoprojeto.descricao')
->join('tipoprojeto','tipoprojeto.id','=','projeto.tipoprojeto')->first();
```

This will make sure only 1 record is returned and that it will return an object instead of a collection